# Laravel / Blade, multiline for @yield default

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know you can do `@yield('section', 'Default Content')`.

I tried:

```
@yield('section')

default<br>
multiline<br>
content<br>

@stop
```

but it didn't work, how can I have a multiline default for @yield?

Answer (score 6):

I found a way, it works doing:

```
@section('section')

default<br>
multiline<br>
content<br>

@stop

@yield('section')
```

Note the `@section` block goes above `@yield`, this way you can have a more readable multiline default for @yield in for example a master page like `app.blade.php`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
@section('section')

default<br>
multiline<br>
content<br>

@stop
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution you could also use an entirely new view as default and render it into `@yield` like this:

```
@yield('section', View::make('section.default'))
```

and then in `section.default.blade.php`

```
default<br>
multiline<br>
content<br>
```